# Laravel: Where to throw HTTP Exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, http, exception, coding-style

#### Background

Within PHP / Laravel MVC applications response codes and bodies are often dictated by the Exception that is thrown. If a HTTP exception is thrown (inheriting from `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`) the correct response codes are thrown (and in certain cases JSON responses). There are other types of exceptions that are non-http related as well that can be thrown.

#### Question

Where should HTTP exceptions be thrown?

- **A** Only the controller
- **B** Anywhere. Deep or shallow in  the applications stack.

Should I be catching my exceptions in the controller and throwing HTTP versions of those exceptions? Or should I just throw a HTTP exception anywhere deep within a service class, repository or utility considering 99% of MVC framework apps are based around a HTTP request >> response lifecycle anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My answer is not targeted at Laravel as I feel working with a framework mindset actually goes against your initial question.

**Always throw a tailored exception** and then handle the conversion within the controller. In this case wrap it in a `HttpException`. There are a few good reasons for this:

- The decision on which status code and message is delegated to the implementation (in this case the integration with your framework). This means that you could drop your code in any framework and handle its errors separately.
- You decide you need a CLI command/worker and now your `HttpException` throws in your service make no sense to your CLI command.

Essentially thinking about a calculator, it would throw a `DivisionByZeroException`. For a controller you would wrap this in a `HttpException` `400 BAD REQUEST` and re-throw. For the CLI your command could just let the exception render on screen `Division By Zero`. **Either way this decision is not made by your service.**

Comment: Well answered with good reasoning. I felt the same just could not seem to grasp why, you have explained why very eloquently

Answer (score 11):

Where should HTTP exceptions be thrown?

While this is generally up to preference, the framework itself seems to have taken an opinionated stance on this and it is that you should be throwing them anywhere. In fact Laravel has a few useful helpers to make throwing exceptions with associated response codes easier:

```
abort(403, "Exception message"); //Will throw an HTTP exception with code 403
abort_if(true, 400, "Condition failed"); //Will throw a 400 error if the first parameter is true
abort_unless(false, 422, "Condition failed"); //Will throw a 422 error if the first parameter is false
```

Practical example:

```
 public function getById($id) { 
      $model = Model::find($id);
      //These are equivalent 
      if ($model == null) {
         abort(404, "$id not found");
      }
      abort_if($model == null, 404, "$id not found");  
      abort_unless($model != null, 404, "$id not found");
 }
```

This is touched upon in the [Error handling section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#http-exceptions) of the manual

Note that `abort` does raise HTTP exceptions so you can still catch them and handle them if you need to.

There seems to be a general misunderstanding regarding this question. It was my understanding that the question was where HTTP exceptions should be thrown but it's evolving to a more generic exception handling in the context of HTTP.

First of all, if you have an HTTP exception, meaning an exception that only makes sense in the context of an HTTP request/response cycle, then you should be able to throw it where it occurs and not throw something else with the purpose of converting it when it reaches the controller, this is what the `abort` helpers are there to do.

However if you have an exception (any kind of exception) that should be interpreted with a specific http response code when left unhandled you have options to deal with that:

1. Make that exception inherit from the Symfony `HttpException` (This might feel a bit strange that a perfectly normal exception inherits from a class that doesn't make sense outside the request/response lifecycle).
2. Implement the [`render` method within your exception](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#render-method) e.g.:

   ```
   class SpecialException extends Exception { 
      public function render() {
           return response()->view('errors.403', [], 403);
      }
   }
   ```
3. Have a specific handling behaviour within your \App\Exceptions\Handler for example:

   ```
   class Handler {
          // ....
         public function render($request, $exception) {
             if ($exception instanceof SpecialException) {
                 return response()->view('errors.403', [], 403);
             }
             return parent::render()
         }
   }
   ```

Comment: I give props for mentioning the documentation but personally the usage of framework specific functions such as `abort` is the same as just throwing the `HttpException` and thus doesn't specifically answer the initial question. In fact using the framework `abort` functionality would be considered worse in my opinion. See my answer for more reasoning.

Comment: @MatthewUsurp the existence and not usage of `abort` is what answers the question. The method is there because Laravel wants to encourage people to throw their HTTP exceptions anywhere within the application. If you disagree with that then that's different to saying that this is not a valid answer.

Comment: I disagree with this answer as it seems to just regurgitate Laravel implementation (Taylor's) and not always best practice or event a good approach.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan personally I find this to be the best practice. If you have a situation where you need to throw an HTTP exception then you should be able to throw it from wherever. Putting a `try...catch` in a controller just so you can turn one exception into another is just messy.

Comment: @apokryfos No. Throwing HTTP exceptions anywhere in your stack couples that code to usage in HTTP environments. What if you later want to use that same code in the console and your throwing HTTP exceptions?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan if you need to throw an **http exception** then your problem isn't that it won't work in the console it's that you decided that an http exception could be thrown by code that's not exclusively ran as part of an http request. An http exception is a very specific type of exception and isn't necessarily applicable everywhere.

Comment: In case it clarifies things I've updated the answer.

Comment: The original question clearly stated this related to HTTP exceptions - of course HTTP is the context. Use of HTTP exceptions outside of a HTTP lifecycle is for sure an anti-pattern and has potential to make your code confusing and mislead developers refactoring and developers debugging in logs.

Comment: If we have the concept of "exception types" that serve the purpose of pointing to the exceptions origin and nature... would it not be a code smell to throw an exception of a type that has not context to the class throwing it?

Comment: I do agree with this, as you said if http is the context then throw an http exception. My point is you should do this wherever it may arise instead of throwing something else and then converting it in the controller. If the context is something else then throw a more context specific exception.